# Problems with x-axis in Jupyter Notebooks with MatPlotLib and Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, graphing

So I have the following code:

```
## BAR PLOTS
#expected value vs probability of choosing option1

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, dpi=320)

data.plot(kind='bar', y='value_1', ax=ax[0],  color ='red')
data.plot(kind='bar', y='p_1', ax=ax[1],  color ='blue')

#ax.set_xlabel("Trials")
#ax.set_ylabel("Value 1 / P_1")

#plt.xticks(np.arange(0, len('value_1')+1, 5), np.arange(0, len('value_1')+1, 5) ) 

#ticks = range(0, 500, 5)
#labels = ticks
#plt.xticks(ticks, labels)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, len(data.value_1)+1, 5), np.arange(0, len(data.value_1)+1, 5) ) 
#ax.legend(["Value 1, P_1"])
plt.title('Bar plots Practice , Expected Vs. Probability')

fig.savefig("figure.pdf")

plt.show()
```

See now The graph is fine, and showing everything that I would want it to show; however, as you can see in this picture below, there is a problem with reading the x-axis / having the tickers spaced out correctly. I've tried to fix it several different ways but have not been able to make it look clean like an excel graph.

[image]

Comment: Matplotlib expect that the x-axis on a bar plot is categorical, and there for every category needs a label. since you haven't shared your data, i'm not sure what your data actually are. But my guess is that you actually just want a `stem` plot

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the figure size,  plt.figure(figsize = (15,15))

Comment: Just made the graph bigger, still the same problem. I added ``` plt.xticks(np.arange(0, len(data.value_1)+1, 5), np.arange(0, len(data.value_1)+1, 5) )  ``` Which fixed the blue graph but not the red, any idea why this might happen

Comment: Is it because the red graph isn't getting much space to expand due to the blue... I am just guessing... Did you try putting blue graph onto the next line...